# Configuring multiple sites(IIS application Pools) with multiple VMs on Azure App Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-application-gateway

We have 3 apps (app1,app2 and app3) that are deployed equally in 2 Azure Vms(vm1 and vm2) - For horizontal scaling

The way it is configured is multiple sites that have multiple URLs with their own application pools on IIS (each server respectively)

So the app urls will look like this now

```
http://vm1-app1       //app1 deployed on vm1
http://vm1-app2       //app2 deployed on vm1
http://vm1-app3       //app3 deployed on vm1
http://vm2-app1       //app1 deployed on vm2
http://vm2-app2       //app2 deployed on vm2
http://vm2-app3       //app3 deployed on vm2
```

Now we are trying to configure the app gateway for this apps

- Configured the backend pool with the 2 VMs
- Created the 3 listeners for 3 apps

Now the question is how can I configure this multiple sites that are configured in each instances ?

I can create backend http settings and override the domain with only 1 host name
e.g, for app1 backend setting I can override the specific domain name as
`vm1-app1` but how can I include the second instance here ?

Another option I can think of is for each app I can create 2 backend settings , each one I can override the host name as `vm1-app1` and `vm2-app1`. But how can I configure these 2 http settings while linking with the rules ?

Am I missing any thing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I overcomplicate things here. After some brief break from work I figured out the solution is rather simple.

Instead of adding the `vm1` and `vm2` as the backends,
I need to add the domain of apps that deployed on the each servers

i.e,

- `vm1-app1` and `vm2-app1` as the backend pool for App1
- `vm1-app2` and `vm2-app2` as the backend pool for App2
- `vm1-app3` and `vm2-app3` as the backend pool for App3

I already have the 3 listeners . So for each listener i need to link the backend pool with a new http backend. Problem Solved.